# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API - Multi-speaker recognition?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

The new Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API is said to be the best in the market. Does it provide speaker annotation (or other speaker information) at all? Like **who** says what at what time. I can't seem to find anywhere on its documentation or examples provided that mentions it.

Both IBM and Amazon do it.

I'd be appreciated if anyone can let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Individual speaker recognition is not currently a feature provided by the API. It’s noted in the issue tracker [1] as a feature request, however there’s no ETA for it currently. I’d recommend starring the issue to receive future comments and updates regarding it.

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/35901846